# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "spree_orders" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree

Once spree(3.1) work on local. Next is to push to heroku. 
I am sure have postgresql. But seem I have to manually do setup table using one of similar rails command.
In the [document](https://github.com/spree/spree) I supposed to run

```
    rails g spree:install --user_class=Spree::User
    rails g spree:auth:install
    rails g spree_gateway:install
```

My first question is how to run those command for heroku

My solution is using these commands

```
   heroku run rake spree:install --user_class=Spree::User
   heroku run rake railties:install:migrations
   heroku run rake db:migrate
   heroku run rake db:seed
   heroku run rake spree_sample:load
```

Comment: So? What happens when you run those commands on Heroku? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: It solved my problem of ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid. But wonder why no one mentioned what to do for heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to run these commands again on heroku.

Just add the files generated by spree to git. Also make sure to add spree migrations to git and then you can just deploy it on heroku.

Followed by

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: OK, I tried after run heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql and git push heroku master to finish deploy. The Spree now ready without sample right?